# Drupal jsonapi cross bundles module usage

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, json-api

I'm setting up a Drupal API, using jsonapi. In the frontend application, we would like to get all content, regardless of content type, with one request. I came across [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_extras/issues/2956414) that adresses exactly that and a module has been worked on: [JSON:API Cross Bundles](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_cross_bundles) I have already installed the module, but I cannot seem to find how to use it. I assumed that I would just be able to request /jsonapi/node to get a response with all my nodes, but that doesn't seem to be how it works. Has anyone actually used this module and can explain to me how to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

Calling jsonapi/node actually works for me. I just enabled the module and it worked out of the box.